# .htaccess - перенаправление запросов

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Необходимо настроить перенаправление запросов.
Структура сайта:

```
example.com/
-- public/
-- -- imgs/
-- -- --- logo.png
-- -- style.css
-- -- script.js
-- index.php
```

Нужно, чтобы при запросе example.com/-a/ сервер возвращал файл из папки public.
То есть, example.com/-a/style.css - файл style.css, example.com/-a/imgs/logo.png - файл logo.png, и т.д. 
Остальные запросы сервер должен направлять в index.php.

Есть такой файл .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^-a\/(.*)$ public/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Но он перенаправляет все на index.php. Помогите пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Я решил данную проблему, спустя 2 часа поисков. Если кому интересно, есть флаг END. Он "отключает" все следующие RewriteRule, если направление произошло.
В итоге получилось так:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^-a\/(.*)$ public/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Теперь все работает.